# backspace working without using it

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, keyboard

it's the first time I using UBUNTU and i'm installling the ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386 version. The problem is that wherever i had to type in some info (like location or rename a drive) during the installation, the typed characters are removed as if there is somebody using the backspace. This happened every second. First i thought it was a hardware problem, but in DOS or Windows there is no problem. (installed after UBUNTU). 
What is here the problem?

Comment: happened to me few times

Comment: And what was the solution?

Comment: I don't know :) when it happens i restart the installation :)